# Google Analytics custom dimension with parent-child relation

Tags: google-analytics

Is it possible set up a custom dimension with a parent-child relationship?
My goal is to be able to see in which program (parent) and which version of the program (child) my app is running.

Basically, what I want to achieve is similar what Google automatically tracks about the operating system (parent) and operating system version (children)

[image: Parent-child relation in Google Analytics]

E.g. for music software I would like it to look like this:

-Music Software Name (parent)
--version (child)
--version (child)

So the actual data could look like this:

Ableton Live (parent)
--9.0.1 (child)
--8.0.5 (child)
Cubase
--8.5.0 (child)
--7.0.1 (child)

Right now I am tracking this within one custom dimension meaning that the date show up like this

Ableton Live, 9.0.1
Ableton Live, 8.0.5
Cubase, 8.5.0
Cubase, 7.0.1

This makes it quite difficult to see how many session there has been from each piece of software as it shows up in the report multiple times (with different version number).

So my question is how to set up custom dimensions to have a parent-child relation just like operating system and operating system version has it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Google Analytics there is no parent-child relationship between dimensions, including OS and OS version; they are connected only insofar as they are sent together in the same hit, so you have also an OS and a version co-occuring. That you can display this as an apparent parent-child relation is just an artefact of the reporting interface (you can just as well create the same report for OS and gender, or browser, or country or almost any other dimension without there being a strong relationship between the two).

So no, you cannot have parent-child relationships, but then you do not need them. That two dimensions are collected in the same hit is enough to create the kind of report you want.